# How to reset the value on variable 'final_features'?

Tags: python, machine-learning, flask, web-applications

```
from typing import List

import numpy as np
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, url_for, redirect
import pickle
import connectiondb
import random

app = Flask(__name__)
model = pickle.load(open('model.pkl', 'rb'))

count = 1

img_id_dic = {
    "1": [3, 12, 15, 13, 5, 6],
    "2": [1, 10, 15, 14, 5, 4],
    "3": [3, 12, 16, 13, 5, 7],
    "4": [1, 11, 16, 14, 6, 3],
    "5": [1, 9, 15, 14, 4, 1],
    "6": [1, 10, 16, 13, 8, 2],
    "7": [1, 10, 15, 14, 4, 5],
    "8": [1, 9, 15, 14, 7, 1],
    "9": [1, 9, 15, 14, 5, 4],
    "10": [3, 9, 15, 13, 5, 6],
    "11": [1, 10, 15, 14, 4, 5],
    "12": [1, 11, 16, 14, 8, 2],
    "13": [3, 12, 16, 13, 6, 7],
    "14": [1, 10, 16, 13, 4, 3],
    "15": [3, 12, 16, 13, 6, 7],
    "16": [3, 12, 16, 13, 4, 3],
    "17": [1, 10, 16, 14, 8, 2],
    "18": [1, 10, 15, 13, 4, 5],
    "19": [1, 12, 15, 13, 5, 6],
    "20": [1, 9, 15, 14, 7, 4],
    "21": [3, 9, 15, 13, 7, 1],
    "22": [1, 9, 15, 14, 8, 4],
    "23": [2, 9, 15, 14, 7, 1],
    "24": [3, 12, 15, 13, 5, 6],
    "25": [1, 10, 16, 14, 4, 5],
    "26": [3, 11, 16, 13, 8, 2],
    "27": [1, 10, 16, 13, 5, 3],
    "28": [2, 11, 16, 13, 5, 7],
    "29": [1, 10, 15, 13, 8, 2],
    "30": [1, 10, 16, 13, 6, 3],
    "31": [3, 9, 15, 13, 6, 7],
    "32": [1, 9, 15, 13, 7, 1],
    "33": [2, 9, 15, 13, 5, 6],
    "34": [1, 10, 15, 14, 7, 4],
    "35": [1, 10, 16, 14, 4, 5],
    "36": [1, 9, 15, 14, 7, 4],
    "37": [1, 10, 16, 14, 4, 5],
    "38": [2, 9, 15, 14, 5, 6],
    "39": [1, 9, 15, 13, 7, 1],
    "40": [3, 11, 16, 13, 8, 7],
    "41": [1, 10, 16, 14, 6, 3],
    "42": [1, 10, 15, 14, 5, 2],
    "43": [1, 9, 16, 14, 5, 6],
    "44": [3, 11, 16, 13, 6, 7],
    "45": [1, 12, 16, 14, 6, 3],
    "46": [1, 9, 15, 14, 8, 2],
    "47": [3, 9, 15, 13, 4, 1],
    "48": [1, 10, 15, 14, 4, 5],
    "49": [1, 9, 15, 14, 7, 4],
    "50": [1, 10, 16, 14, 4, 5],
    "51": [1, 9, 15, 14, 7, 4],
    "52": [1, 9, 15, 14, 8, 2],
    "53": [3, 9, 15, 13, 7, 1],
    "54": [3, 10, 15, 13, 5, 7],
    "55": [1, 9, 16, 14, 5, 6],
    "56": [1, 10, 16, 14, 6, 3],
    "57": [1, 11, 15, 14, 5, 6],
    "58": [1, 11, 16, 13, 4, 3],
    "59": [1, 9, 15, 14, 4, 1],
    "60": [3, 12, 16, 13, 6, 7],
    "61": [1, 9, 15, 14, 8, 2],
    "62": [1, 10, 15, 14, 4, 5],
    "63": [1, 9, 15, 14, 5, 4],
    "64": [1, 10, 16, 13, 4, 5],
    "65": [1, 9, 15, 14, 5, 4],
    "66": [1, 12, 15, 14, 8, 2],
    "67": [1, 9, 15, 14, 4, 1],
    "68": [2, 9, 15, 14, 6, 7],
    "69": [3, 12, 16, 14, 5, 6],
    "70": [1, 11, 16, 14, 6, 3],
    "71": [1, 12, 15, 14, 5, 6],
    "72": [3, 12, 15, 14, 4, 3],
    "73": [2, 12, 15, 13, 5, 7],
    "74": [1, 9, 15, 14, 7, 1],
    "75": [1, 9, 15, 14, 5, 2],
    "76": [1, 9, 15, 14, 7, 4],
    "77": [1, 10, 15, 14, 4, 5],
    "78": [1, 10, 16, 14, 4, 5],
    "79": [1, 12, 16, 14, 8, 4],
    "80": [1, 12, 16, 14, 8, 2],
    "81": [1, 9, 15, 13, 7, 1],
    "82": [3, 12, 15, 13, 6, 7],
    "83": [1, 9, 15, 13, 6, 3],
    "84": [1, 12, 15, 14, 5, 6],
    "85": [1, 10, 16, 14, 6, 3],
    "86": [3, 11, 16, 13, 7, 7],
    "87": [1, 12, 15, 14, 5, 6],
    "88": [1, 9, 15, 14, 7, 1],
    "89": [1, 10, 15, 13, 4, 5],
    "90": [2, 11, 15, 13, 8, 2],
    "91": [1, 9, 15, 14, 5, 4],
    "92": [1, 9, 15, 14, 7, 1],
    "93": [1, 12, 15, 14, 6, 6],
    "94": [3, 10, 15, 14, 7, 1],
    "95": [1, 12, 15, 13, 5, 7],
    "96": [3, 9, 15, 13, 7, 1],
    "97": [1, 9, 15, 13, 5, 2],
    "98": [3, 9, 15, 14, 7, 1],
    "99": [1, 12, 16, 14, 8, 2],
    "100": [1, 9, 15, 14, 6, 3],
    "101": [3, 9, 15, 14, 7, 1],
    "102": [1, 12, 15, 14, 6, 3],
    "103": [1, 12, 16, 14, 6, 3]

}

emo_id_dict = {
    1: "happy",
    2: "sad",
    3: "fear",
    4: "contempt",
    5: "surprise",
    6: "anger",
    7: "disgust",
    8: "not sure"
}


def num_to_emotions(num):
    return emo_id_dict[num]


@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')


@app.route('/main')
def main():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    print("if")
    global count
    print(count)
    if count <= 103:

        img_urls = connectiondb.myresult[count - 1]
        print("dict values", img_id_dic[str(count)])
        int_features = img_id_dic[str(count)]

        print(int_features)
        user_id = int(request.form["users"])
        int_features.insert(6, user_id)
        print(int_features)

        final_features = [np.array(int_features)]
        prediction = model.predict(final_features)

        count += 1

        return render_template('index.html', prediction_text=num_to_emotions(prediction[0]),
                               images=img_urls[1], originval=img_urls[2])

    else:
        print("else")
        print(count)
        count = 1

        print(count)
        return redirect(url_for('redo'))


@app.route('/redo')
def redo():
    return render_template('end.html')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I am trying to create a machine learning analyzer. I am using a **model.pkl** file to run this **app.py** file. Which holds the model of a **SVM model for 7-features**. The problem that raises from the above code is that, the **feature turns to 8 once I reach 103 images** and redirect back to the same page to analyze the answers of a different set of users response. Thank you for the help.

**Traceback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dev07cpu\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2463, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\dev07cpu\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2449, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\dev07cpu\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1866, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\dev07cpu\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\dev07cpu\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\dev07cpu\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\dev07cpu\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\dev07cpu\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\dev07cpu\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\dev07cpu\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\xampp\htdocs\Web-Interfacee\csv\Model-Area\testing\app.py", line 164, in predict
    prediction = model.predict(final_features)
  File "C:\Users\dev07cpu\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\_base.py", line 594, in predict
    y = super().predict(X)
  File "C:\Users\dev07cpu\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\_base.py", line 315, in predict
    X = self._validate_for_predict(X)
  File "C:\Users\dev07cpu\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\_base.py", line 467, in _validate_for_predict
    (n_features, self.shape_fit_[1]))
ValueError: X.shape[1] = 8 should be equal to 7, the number of features at training time
```

Comment: Can you provide the traceback?

Comment: I have edited the post.